# Unsorted list top margin with or without text before it

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.content {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
ul {
  padding-top:0;
  margin-top:0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class='content'>
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

That works great for what I need as far as the `padding top` inside 'content', but sometimes it's possible there will be text before the `ul`:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class='content'>
  Some Text
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul
</div>
```

I'd like there to be a space between the text and the unsorted list, but if I add a `margin` or `padding top` to the `<ul>`, the spacing gets too large if the text is not present. I need to come up with CSS that works with both scenarios. Unfortunately, I don't have control over the markup so I can't add a line break or wrap that intro text into another `div`. I also tried using:

```
.content > ul {margin-top:10px}
.content > ul:first-child {margin-top: 0}
```

As well as

```
.content > * + ul { margin-top:10px}
```

Neither of these work. Regardless of text being present or not, the `<ul>` is always treated as the first `child`.

Comment: mind moving the padding on content to a margin on the h1? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwXZVK

Comment: @MichaelCoker that works! for some reason i thought the 2 margins would conflict. please post as the answer and I will accept. Thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some trickery utilizing [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing), you can add a `margin-bottom` to your `h1`, then a `margin-top` on the `ul`.

Since the `div` that wraps the `ul` doesn't have padding, a border, or any content (when there is no text), the `margin-top` will collapse outside of the parent and be applied to the `div` instead, then that margin and the bottom margin on the `h1` will collapse as adjacent siblings.

Then when you add inline content to the `div`, that contains the margin on the `ul` to be within the `div`

```css
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ul {
  padding-top:0;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class='content'>
  text
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.content > ul` and `.content > ul:first-child` are same so there is conflict.you first add `margin:10px` and after it add `margin:0px`.

`margin:0px` is winner  Because come after `margin:10px`.

```css
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content ul {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class='content'>
  Some Text
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```